# Django Forms pyodbc Mssql TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting

Tags: django, pyodbc

I'm developing an web app alongside an existing windows app on SQL server 2014.Using the following settings

```
DATABASES = {
'default': {
    'NAME': ' Name',
    'ENGINE': 'sql_server.pyodbc',
    'SERVER': 'server',
    'USER': 'sa',
    'PASSWORD': 'password',

    'OPTIONS':
     {
     'driver_supports_utf8': True,
      'autocommit': True,
      'unicode_results': True,
      'host_is_server':True,
      'driver': 'SQL Server Native Client 11.0',
      }
    }
    }
```

I'm Using stored procedures in my django app to use the existing functionalities

```
class Viewpatform(forms.Form):
Name = forms.CharField(max_length=100)
Phone_Number = forms.IntegerField(label='Phone Number', required=True)
Sex = forms.ChoiceField(widget=forms.Select(choices=sexchoice))
Age = forms.IntegerField(label='Age')
AgeType = forms.ChoiceField(choices=Agetype,  required=True,  label='Type')
Address = forms.CharField(max_length=500, required=False)
Registration_Date = forms.DateField( label='Registration Date')
with connection.cursor() as cursor:
   cursor.execute(''' EXEC dbo.insert_patients @Name = ?, -- varchar(100)
    @Phone_Number = ?, -- int
    @Age = ?, -- int
    @AgeType = ?, -- int
    @Address = ?, -- varchar(200)
    @sex = ? -- varchar(2)
         ''', [ Name, Phone_Number, Sex, Age, AgeType, Address] )
```

I have been getting the following errors while executing the form

> File "c:\python35\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 79, in execute
>       return super(CursorDebugWrapper, self).execute(sql, params)
>     File "c:\python35\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 64, in execute
>       return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
>     File "c:\python35\lib\site-packages\sql_server\pyodbc\base.py", line 535, in execute
>       sql = self.format_sql(sql, params)
>     File "c:\python35\lib\site-packages\sql_server\pyodbc\base.py", line 503, in format_sql
>       sql = sql % tuple('?' * len(params))
>   TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting

Django ver 1.10
Windows 7 64 bit 
Django-Pyodbc-azure : Version: 1.10.4.0
Python 3.5

Comment: Why did you write stored procedures for simple inserts like this in the first place? All you achieve is to make things rather complicated. You don't generally use cursors in django because we have a fantastic ORM. That cursor based insert is a one liner using the Django ORM

Comment: @e4c5 I'm using all the existing stored procedures , I didn't want to reorganize my models according to the new app and the existing web app is in production with enhancements going on , I would be able to cover them too by using SPs

Comment: what is the point of writing a stored procedure for a simple insert? The code to call the stored procedure is more complicated than the one liner to insert with the ORM. Sorry you have got this wrong.

Comment: @e4c5 the Insert SP affects around 5 Tables with many checks within the SP , Rather than rewriting the code I found it easier to just Run the SP which is already in production

Comment: in which case it means you haven't asked a proper question to begin with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your arguments appear to be out of order. You must pass the arguments in the list of parameters in the same order as the question mark place holders:

```
cursor.execute(
    '''
        EXEC dbo.insert_patients
            @Name = ?, -- varchar(100)
            @Phone_Number = ?, -- int
            @Age = ?, -- int
            @AgeType = ?, -- int
            @Address = ?, -- varchar(200)
            @sex = ? -- varchar(2)
    ''',
    [Name, Phone_Number, Age, AgeType, Address, Sex]
)
```

You're getting the error because you're passing integers as strings and strings as integers, AFAIK. Good luck!